# ErrorNo 150 mySQL

Tags: mysql

I have this problem when I try to create two foreign key in the same table
 how I can fix it & thank you

```
create table employee(
employeeNumber INT (11) primary key,

);


create table projects(

projectNumber INT(11) primary key ,

);

create table workat(
wemployeeNumber INT(11),
wprojectNUmber INT (11),
primary key (wemployeeNumber,wprojectNUmber),    
FOREIGN key workat(wemployeeNumber) references employee(employeeNumber), 
FOREIGN key workat(wprojectNUmber) references projects(projectNumber) 

);
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you encounter? :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your `FOREIGN KEY` syntax looks off to me, and I don't know why you wrap the definition in `workat`.  Try this version:

```
CREATE TABLE workat (
    wemployeeNumber INT(11),
    wprojectNUmber INT(11),
    PRIMARY KEY (wemployeeNumber, wprojectNumber),    
    FOREIGN KEY (wemployeeNumber) REFERENCES employee (employeeNumber), 
    -- projects, not project
    FOREIGN KEY (wprojectNUmber)  REFERENCES projects (projectNumber) 
);
```

Here is a demo showing that your code compiles after making the above changes:

### Demo

Comment: create table workat (
    wemployeeNumber INT(11),
    wprojectNUmber INT (11),
    primary key (wemployeeNumber,wprojectNUmber),    
    FOREIGN key wemployeeNumber references employee(employeeNumber), 
    FOREIGN key wprojectNUmber references project(projectNumber) 
);


didn't work

Comment: @riadhgazouna ...and...what happened next?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  He has 2 other typos in his example, your answer repeats one of them, otherwise it's perfect. Plus one to you and let him hunt it down himself.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen  this error  #1005 - Can't create table `company`.`workat` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (Details…)

Comment: @riadhgazouna Check my demo for a working example.  You also have stray commas in the first two create table statements.